# I need to know what are the more than four bytes character in UTF-16 and what is the range of code in UTF-16?

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters, utf-16

I need to know what are the more than four bytes character in UTF-16 and what is the range of code in UTF-16?

I have looked for on internet and here without success, someone have some material to share?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: There are no "more than four bytes" UTF-16-encoded code points.  U+0000 to U+FFFF encode in two bytes, and U+10000 to U+10FFFF encode in 4 bytes.

Comment: It depends on what do you mean for character. On stricter sense, these are just 2 or 4 bytes. But one or more characters can form a glyph (and a glyph cluster), which may be seen as "character" (e.g. it may have just one design in a font). And technically speaking, some of such combined characters are canonical equivalent to a single character. The topic is complex, so the terminology. So treat a Unicode string as blackbox (if you can), else you should query shaper and font or a segmentation library to know better about the cluster.

Comment: [1] In the absence of any programming aspect to your question, I think it is off topic for Stack Overflow. You might have more luck asking it on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). [2] You might also consider clarifying the problem. As an earlier comment correctly noted, there are no UTF-16 encoded characters that are _"more than four bytes"_, but there can be grapheme clusters more than four bytes long, representing user perceived characters comprised of multiple codepoints: a base character and multiple combining characters. What you are actually asking is unclear, to me at least.

Comment: Hi there, thank you all for your answers. @Mark Tolonen, I am really confused because in this amazon link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html#c_Supported_data_types-multi-byte-characters they talk about "more than five-byte or longer characters are not supported", what are these characters? and what is its range? Thanks

Comment: I need to know how to identify them, so that I can remove them using pyspark

Comment: The UTF-8 encoding algorithm, not UTF-16, can support 1-6 bytes, but Unicode code points are formally defined as U+0000 to U+10FFFF. That range fits in 1-4 bytes.

Comment: As others have commented, encodings deal with code points, but “user perceived characters” or “graphemes” can be made up of multiple code points.

Comment: Hi @Mark Tolonen, I understood that we just can see characters  but just to confirm what you said means that I just have to exclude the Unicode code points that are not within this range? another question, how I know the range of  Unicode code points of the emojis? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unicode defines a set of code points. Each of those code point has an associated graphical representation (i.e. the character as we know of it). The code point values range in 0 to 0x10ffff.

UTF-8 and UTF-16 are ways to represent those code points. UTF-8 is a variable length representation. UTF-16 is a fixed length representation taking 16bits.

As you may have already guessed, 16bits numbers cannot represent values greater than 0xffff. There comes what is called the "surrogate" to encode code points between 0x100000 and 0x10ffff. This leads code points between 0x100000 and 0x10ffff use two 16bits to encode their value.

For instance, the code point of the letter `A` is `0x41` and its UTF-16 representation is `0x0041`.

For instance, the code point for  is `0x100000` and its UTF-16 representation is `0xD800DC00`.

In any case, the UTF-16 encoding does not define rules which would lead any of the code points being encoded using more than 4bytes..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be in the wording of the question, which asks a reasonable question: When reading in text in Unicode format, will there be characters which take up more than 4 bytes?"

The answer is *yes*, absolutely, because of how Unicode "builds up" characters by combining them with various markers.

Let's take, for example, the following character:

‍‍

This depicts a darks-skinned couple holding hands.

However, this single character actually represents a combination of several characters:

```
'\u200d\u200d'
```

`\u200d` represents a zero-width joiner and in this case is interpreted as "Person, with dark skin, joined to handshake, joined to person, with dark skin"

The first character in *this* multicharacter string is *also* multiple characters:

(U+1F9D1, Adult) and the second character indicates that it should be rendered with dark skin tone.

Here is the breakdown of ‍‍ as unicode names:

```
 ADULT
 EMOJI MODIFIER FITZPATRICK TYPE-6
‍ ZERO WIDTH JOINER
 HANDSHAKE
‍ ZERO WIDTH JOINER
 ADULT
 EMOJI MODIFIER FITZPATRICK TYPE-6
```

The total bytes for this *single character* is **26 bytes long**. Here it is encoded in UTF-8:

```
\xf0\x9f\xa7\x91\xf0\x9f\x8f\xbf\xe2\x80\x8d\xf0\x9f\xa4\x9d\xe2\x80\x8d\xf0\x9f\xa7\x91\xf0\x9f\x8f\xbf
```

So you can see it is very possible for a single "character" to have more than 4 bytes, because of how the Unicode standard combines multiple characters into single characters.

Even fairly "standard" characters like flags are actually 8 bytes long.

If you are using Python, the easiest way to identify if a *single* character is more than 4 bytes long is to get its length using `len`:

```
>>> seemingly_single_character=""
>>> print(single_character)

>>> len(seemingly_single_character)
2
```